# SELECT INTO OUTFILE WITH "WHERE" statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export the DB records from the table via "SELECT INTO OUTFILE".
Everything works. But I need to filter the records and this is the problem.
Here's the code:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '%John%' AND LENGTH(name) <= 10 ORDER BY name
```

This statement doesn't work, but if I remove the "name LIKE '%John%'" condition, it works.
But I need to specify this LIKE condition, how can I accomplish it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "*this statement doesn't work*"?  What happens?  What results, or error, do you get?  What did you expect?

Comment: I perform this query through the Wordpress `WPDB` class. It doesn't return anything. I expect to receive the file.

Comment: And if you execute the query without the `INTO OUTFILE` clause?  Are there actually any records which satisfy the criteria `WHERE name LIKE '%John%' AND LENGTH(name) <= 10`?  Please show an example.

Comment: I've tried to execute the query through `mysql_query` and it works.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".TMPDIR."export.txt'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' from wp_domrail where 1=1 and domain_name LIKE '%asia%' and LENGTH(domain_name) <= 10 ORDER BY domain_name");`

Comment: And you're saying that that query *works*?  If so, what's the problem?  I'm confused.

Comment: I've deleted the `$wpdb->prepare` method inside `$wpdb->query` method and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a problem with the `%`sign. Try replacing

```
WHERE name LIKE '%John%'
```

with

```
WHERE LOCATE(name, 'John') > 0
```

Comment: What could possibly be the problem with the `%` sign?

Comment: I read in a thread that about WPDB: `However, when I try to use it to add a row where one cell contains the percent sign ("%"), nothing happens.`

Comment: Answer was: `prepare() expects a sprintf() format string, in which the % is used to
prefix placeholder types. You can use a literal % by prepending it
with another %: %%.`